# GCP Cloud Composer is failed to create with native-VPC setting

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

Airflow Cluster should communicate with resources in `dev-vpc`, I've noticed that I should place the airflow cluster on the same vpc and set the vpc-native on, in order to access the resources with a private ip.

The picture on below is my network setting.

[image: network_setting]

The Kubernetes cluster, However, is failed to start correctly and shows following error.

```
Status details

All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 2 nodes out of 3 have registered; this is likely due to Nodes failing to start correctly; try re-creating the cluster or contact support if that doesn't work.
```

The following log is the error logged from Cloud Composer.

```
{
 insertId: "-<my_insert_id>"  
 logName: "projects/<my_project_name>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
 operation: {
  id: "projects/new-life-experience/locations/asia-northeast3/operations/<operation_id>"   
  last: true   
  producer: "composer.googleapis.com"   
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "<my_email>"    
  }
  methodName: "google.cloud.orchestration.airflow.service.v1.Environments.CreateEnvironment"   
  resourceName: "projects/<my_project_name>/locations/asia-northeast3/environments/<my_composer_name>"   
  serviceName: "composer.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code: 2    
   message: "Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage: CP_COMPOSER_AGENT_RUNNING
description: "RPC Successful: Pull"
response_timestamp {
  seconds: 1591150022
  nanos: 653000000
}
]."    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-06-03T02:09:01.854953208Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   environment_name: "<my_composer_name>"    
   location: "asia-northeast3"    
   project_id: "<my_project_id>"    
  }
  type: "cloud_composer_environment"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-06-03T02:09:01.232Z"
```

I've already checked quota of the instances but all of the quota is enough to assign three nodes for Composer.

I don't know why only two out of three nodes are assigned successfully, when creating the kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Can you share the documentation you have followed? Thanks!

Comment: @muscat I've followed following document https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/configuring-private-ip?_ga=2.103070982.-745502190.1577056197&_gac=1.218312299.1591099881.CjwKCAjw8df2BRA3EiwAvfZWaOF7WbG_T_2nxP_8JfkG9ZVHLmyWw4aTOPepZpEAr9EqAcoSYO7OKhoCCXYQAvD_BwE#secondary-range

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use the default network and subnetwork?

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal No, I used the VPC that I created, and the subnet that has automatically generated to the region with the VPC. Btw, I created the VPC with `Automatic subnet generation on` can it be the problem?

Comment: I see, could you please confirm that you have followed access control [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#access-control) before creating the environment? As I can understand you have followed 10 steps from the doc you provided. Additionally take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips), and see important notes.

Comment: @muscat I've followed the VPC IP range one. But I realized that service account permissions can cause problems as you mentioned! I am going to try this!

Comment: It's unlikely a service account related issue would cause only 2/3 nodes to come up in an Instance Group. @astrohsy, can you access the GKE cluster page and click on the default-pool, then node pool to see what the status of the unhealthy third node is? On that page, it will give you a more specific reason for why it couldn't come up.

Comment: @hexacyanide Thanks for your help! I've started the composer cluster today with the same environment but It works fine. I think there was a bug on the asia-northeast3 region, which is currently released.

Comment: @astrohsy I've posted community wiki answer to inform community about the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was provided by @astrohsy in the comment section:

> I've started the Composer cluster today with the same environment but
>   It works fine. I think there was a bug on the `asia-northeast3`
>   region, which is currently released.